# Trouble with object array as object property in VBA Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private oiCustoms() As CCustomClass
Public Property Get Partners() As CCustomClass()
    Set Partners() = oiCustoms()
End Property

Public Property Set Partners(values() As CCustomClass)
    ReDim oiPartners(values.Count)
    Set oiCustoms() = values()
End Property
```

When I try to run I get a Compile error:
Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procudure has n optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid Set final parameter.

What's wrong here?  I have done some looking, and it looks like I can't use an array as a property parameter.  Is this correct?  Any good workarounds.  I will need to have this data for the object stored in an array for use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing arrays with objects.

```
Private oiCustoms() As CCustomClass
Public Property Get Partners() As CCustomClass()
    Partners = oiCustoms
End Property

Public Property Let Partners(values() As CCustomClass)
    ReDim oiPartners(LBound(values) To UBound(values))
    oiCustoms = values
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had thought that an object array would need to use set.